# Which file is the boot critical file that is corrupt/damaged?

Tags: windows-7, boot, filesystem-corruption

Trying to figure out which file needs to be repaired.

Running windows x64 home premium

I don't have a optical drive on the laptop, but have sub drives.windo

The startup repair log says:

```
Bugcheck c000021a
Parameters = oxfffff8a00009a1co ...
Boot critical file is corrupt.

Repair action: File repair
Result: failed. Error code = 0x2
```

Sometimes when I start the laptop and try startup repair, I just get a blue screen of death: bsod

[image: bsod]

[image: start option]

[image: windows failed to start]

[image: boot critical file is corrupt]

Comment: I figured out my laptop battery was getting too hot (made in China no name) which caused the laptop to shut off. I removed the battery and have not noticed any random power shut offs.

Answer (score -1):

**STOP: 0xC000021A**

**Cause**

This error occurs when a user-mode subsystem, such as WinLogon or the Client Server Run-Time Subsystem (CSRSS), has been fatally compromised and security can no longer be guaranteed. In response, the operating system switches to kernel mode. Microsoft Windows cannot run without WinLogon or CSRSS. Therefore, this is one of the few cases where the failure of a user-mode service can shut down the system.

Mismatched system files can also cause this error. This can occur if you have restored your hard disk from a backup. Some backup programs might skip restoring system files that they determine are in use.
Resolving the Problem

Running the kernel debugger is not useful in this situation because the actual error occurred in a user-mode process.

Resolving an error in a user-mode device driver, system service, or third-party application:Because bug check 0xC000021A occurs in a user-mode process, the most common culprits are third-party applications. If the error occurred after the installation of a new or updated device driver, system service, or third-party application, the new software should be removed or disabled. Contact the manufacturer of the software about a possible update.

If the error occurs during system startup, restart your computer, and press F8 at the character-based menu that displays the operating system choices. At the resulting WindowsAdvanced Options menu, choose the Last Known Good Configuration option. This option is most effective when only one driver or service is added at a time. If this does not resolve the error, try manually removing the offending software. If the system partition is formatted with file allocation table (FAT), use an MS-DOS startup disk to gain access to the computer's hard disk. If the system partition is formatted with NTFS file system, you might be able to use Safe Mode to rename or delete the faulty software. If the faulty software is used as part of the system startup process in Safe Mode, you need to start the computer using the Recovery Console in order to access the file. If a newly installed piece if hardware is suspected, remove it to see if this resolves the issue.

Try running the Emergency Recovery Disk (ERD) and allow the system to repair any errors that it detects.

Resolving a mismatched system file problem: If you have recently restored your hard disk from a backup, check if there is an updated version of the Backup/Restore program available from the manufacturer. Make sure the latest Windows Service Pack is installed.

Source: http://answers.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/forum/windows_7-system/blue-screen-error-c000021a-fatal-system-error/549075f8-f695-4047-b747-2b4e118e1ffd

Comment: Where did you copy and paste that from? Source?

Comment: shoot, I forgot to add that before going to sleep

Comment: This is a low effort answer. Your line "If the error occurs during system startup" reiterates that, as OP clearly states when it happens.

Comment: @Fusseldieb 9 years later. Necro much?

Comment: Yes @td512, and you're contributing to it. It is a low-effort answer and should be revised. Remember, just because it's old, doesn't mean it's no longer relevant, especially on StackOverflow!